# Python Curses UI printing Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

Hello I am making a simple Curses UI app I have everything working. I am trying to print this █ in my progress bar but when I do i get this error

```
File "simple.py", line 100, in <module>                                                                       │
│           main()                                                             │
│           File "simple.py", line 55, in main                         │
│           show_progress()      │
│           File "simple.py", line 83, in show_progress                                         │
│           win.addstr(1,pos,u"\u2588")          │
│UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2588' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I Know this is a horrible error but it is how it is printed out

Here is the code that is printing it

```
win.addstr(1,pos,u"\u2588")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2 does not understand Unicode - it only understands bytes...

So port to Python3 (Easy unless you are doing Network programming) or start doing

```
bytes(unicode_string.encode('utf-8'))
```

Everywhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you this worked, I converted the code with 2to3 and it run perfect